# Casting static variables in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I am trying to create unique primary IDs for my SQLite database by casting a static integer as a character that then is included in my SQL command.

My code is:

```
/*Global Variables*/
static int ID = 1;
sqlite3 *db;//pointer to db
char *zErrMsg = 0;//initialize 
int rc = sqlite3_open("database.db", &db);//open connection;

int main(){
   char str[150];
   char userName[9]; char password[9]; char ip[9];
   char uniqID = (char)('0'+(int)ID);
   printf("Enter username: "); gets(userName);
   printf("Enter password: "); gets(password);
   printf("Enter IP: "); gets(ip);

   strcpy(str, "INSERT INTO USERS (ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD,IP) "  \
            "VALUES (");
   strcat(str, uniqID);
   strcat(str, ", '");
   strcat(str, user);
   strcat(str, "', '");
   strcat(str, password);
   strcat(str, "', '");
   strcat(str, ip);
   strcat(str, "');");

   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, str, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   (rc != SQLITE_OK) ? fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg) : fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
   ID++;
}
```

This would be a function later so that when the function would be called uniqID would be incremented by 1 to become a new primary key for each new entry into my table.

The error that I am getting pertains to `strcat(str, uniqID);` and is throwing `incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with &[-Wint-conversion]`

Printing the character is fine, but concatenating it with the rest of the string is where I am running into difficulties. What can I do to solve this issue?

What I don't understand is that although the value of `uniqID` is reliant on `ID`, once uniqID is declared, if ID changes, the changes do not impact the character uniqID (it does not dynamically change with the value of ID) because it is retaining its prior value. Because of this I figured `uniqID` is just assigned the ASCII value of `ID` when it is assigned.

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: `strcat(str, uniqID);`.

Comment: You realize you are always using `1` as the ID?

Comment: The function `strcat` takes parameters by reference, not by value.  You are passing by value it seems. Try `strcat(str, &uniqID);`

Comment: @staticx Yes. But I want to add ID++ at the end of the function with each function call so that it changes. this was just put in a main() function in order simplify.

Comment: `char buf[9]; gets(buf);` ... My Eyes! The goggles do nothing!

Comment: ...and to continue my comment, here's [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15618797/1717300) outlining why `gets` is evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcat` expects a null-terminated string. You need to take the integer and convert it to a null-terminated string via the `itoa` function.

Essentially the way your code reads right now is you're adding the value of the character 0 in ASCII to your ID and then casting the whole thing to a char and then passing that as the address (since it thinks it's a pointer) to the `strcat` function.

As an aside, using `gets` to collect data that is a fixed length (e.g., your username is of length 9) is a recipe for buffer overflows. I recommend using `fgets` because it allows you to pass in a buffer length.

Comment: when trying to use `itoa(ID, uniqID, 10);` I received the error `implicit declaration of function 'itoa' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Comment: `itoa` is non-standard. You can also use `•sprintf(str,"%d",value)` to do the conversion in a standard way.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that ID will return to '1' every time the program is executed.

```
static int ID = 1;
```

---

---

```
   char uniqID = (char)('0'+(int)ID);        //  Remove this line.
```

---

```
      strcat(str, uniqID);                   // <-- Change this line to
      snprintf(&str[strlen(str)], "%d", ID); // <-- to this line.
```